# How to calculate the probability of a random sequence of bits being a specific sequence?

Tags: probability

If, for example, I have `0011` as a set of known bits $x$, how do I determine the probability that a sequence of randomly generated bits is equal to $x$?

Thanks for the help! I'm sure this is a dumb question, but probability has always been my weakness (which my algorithms class is highlighting!).

*EDIT:* This is what I should've asked:

How do you find the probability of randomly getting `0011` on the left-side of an 8-bit sequence?

Comment: Hint: by "randomly" you probably mean that all such sequences have the same probability.  So: how many possible sequences of four bits are there?

Comment: $2^4$, right? For each entry, a bit can either be 0 or 1, so it's $2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2$. I believe I'm looking for a permutation, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to add order to it. For $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$, my $n$ is 4, but it seems my $r$ would also be 4, leading to $4!$. This doesn't really seem right, but I know I shouldn't be trusting my intuition in these matters!

Comment: @Michael Why do permutations matter?  You have just correctly counted all possible strings of four bits.  An axiom of probability is that the sum of all probabilities is 1.  Thus, the sum of your 16 equal probabilities equals 1.  Solve the equation!

Comment: @whuber Sorry -- I was thinking permutations because of something I failed to mention -- I'm looking for the probability of `0011` being the left half of an 8 bit sequence (e.g., `00110000`). So, this was kind of leading me to $\Pr[leftHalf = 0011] = 1/P^{8}_{4} = 0.000595$, but it didn't seem right. (My goal in this problem is to explain the behavior I'm observing in terms of probabilities. If only Proof by Example wasn't a joke!)

Comment: @Michael The answer to your expanded question depends on whether the right and left halves are independent.  If they are, you can ignore the right half (and you're already done!).  If they are not, you need to describe how the values depend on one another.

Comment: @whuber Great -- the right half is independent. So you're saying $1/16$ would give me the correct probability? Thanks for all of your help on this!